# Update DataSet in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, dataset

I have little to no experience in using Datasets and Crystal Reports so please don't bash me if the answer is really obvious, I didn't manage to find the answer on-line.

I have a C# Winforms application, containing a Crystal Report that takes its data from a DataSet. I populate the DataSet dynamically from inside the application.

In the past, if I added another column to the DataSet, I could right click the DataSet in the Crystal Report and click "Verify Database" to make the new columns available in the Report.

Now, if I do this the following window pops up:

[image]

There is no item available in the Class Name combobox, and if I check the checkbox, another combobox appears which is also empty.

Please note that I populate the DataSet from inside the program, so there is no connection.

How can I update the DataSet in the Crystal Reports, so that the new columns become available?

Thank you.

P.S.: I have tried the following solution but it didn't work: [Update DataSet Schema On Crystal Reports for VS2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959814/update-dataset-schema-on-crystal-reports-for-vs2008) because I am presented with the same window as above.

Also, this is what I see, might be useful:

[image]

Edit1: The fields appear in the Data Sources but do not appear in the Field Explorer.

I already have some Formula Fields that have the same name as the newly added Columns but removing them didn't help either.

Comment: Have you tried typing the name of your class into the field?

Comment: You could also look at [Crystal Report VerifyDatabase not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877824/crystal-report-verifydatabase-not-working) and [tables not found during Verify Database](http://wisdomofsl.com/2011/06/18/crystal-reports-tables-not-found-during-verify-database/) for other things to try.

Comment: I do not use any classes for this (none that I'm aware of). Also, none of the articles you provided help, but thank you for trying.

Comment: Maybe, [Adding a column to a DataSet (xsd) for a Crystal Report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575169/adding-a-column-to-a-dataset-xsd-for-a-crystal-report)?

Comment: [Updating Crystal Reports .NET if You Change the XSD](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/rjdudley/archive/2005/05/27/2606.aspx) sounds like it addresses the same issue.

Comment: Joshua, thanks for trying. I managed to solve it on my own though. I'll post the solution when the system will allow me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it by myself. There are three things I did and I'm not quite sure which one did the trick since I can't seem to manage to recreate the problem.

1. I renamed the Formula Fields that had the same name as the DataTable columns I added.
2. I clicked the " ... " box and reselected the same file.
3. I added the Internal Connection ID {294de39c-3e3c-4748-9138-53d4be2a74a6} in the Class Name textbox.

The first two probably didn't help since they didn't work before. It did work when I added the string so that's probably the solution, but this didn't work the first time either.

Hopefully my wasted hours would save someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. Here is the steps:

1. Create New DataSet and drag the table from SQL Server ObjectExplorer
2. Right click on Database Fields
3. Choose Datasource Location
4. Click on the table on new DataSet created on step 1
5. Click Update

Hope it can help